Mac (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError
I am trying to connect to the NSE site using one of the Python libraries from Macbook.  It's throwing SSL Error.
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_stdlib_context
from datetime import date
from nsepy import get_history
sbin = get_history(symbol='SBIN',start=date(2024,4,1),
                   end=date(2024,4,4))

Full Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 509, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1046, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1317, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 793, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 847, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www1.nseindia.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE&segmentLink=3&dateRange=&symbol=SBIN&series=EQ&symbolCount=1&fromDate=01-04-2024&toDate=04-04-2024 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  

  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 266, in resolve_redirects
    resp = self.send(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/

adapters.py", line 517, in send
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www1.nseindia.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?
dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE&segmentLink=3&dateRange=&symbol=SBIN&series=EQ&symbolCount=1&fromDate=01-04-2024&toDate=04-04-2024 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError
(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

I did try. installing
Installing Certificate.command

Update Shell Profile. command.

Added
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_stdlib_context

Added nse certificate in key chain access.
Tried to upgrade the certificate.
pip install --upgrade certifi

But it didn't worked. Can you please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks

Mac firewall issue. Took help from the Mac service center guy and was able to add exceptions to the firewall.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
